# How to Translate All Instances of Carbon instead of translatedFormat() individually

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am having an issue with outputting the dates in user's preferred language. I have a middleware, registered in kernel, which renders the app according to preferred locale for that user.

```
                \App::setLocale($user->locale);
                setlocale(LC_ALL, config('app.locale'));
                Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

this doesn't change language of carbon dates (application language changes as it should). When i check the settings by showing them on a blade view, application is setting the selected locale for carbon correctly.

But i can only display the date in selected language, if I use `translatedFormat()` function for that specific instance, i think i may have over 100 instances, for some, i use accessors to format the output in my models.  Is this normal behavior? I have to do this individually? I thought I was setting the locale globally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$user->locale` is user preferred locale but `config('app.locale')` is not (it's application fallback locale).

```
\App::setLocale($user->locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $user->locale);
Carbon::setLocale($user->locale);
```

And in theory `\App::setLocale` already change the `Carbon` locale too and last, `setlocale` is only used when relying on OS translations (such when using the old method `Carbon::formatLocalized`) but you should rather use `isoFormat`, `calendar`, `diffForHumans` or such methods that rely on `Carbon` embedded translations and so don't need to change the `LC_ALL` setting. So `\App::setLocale($user->locale);` should just be enough. But then you need to use methods that actually translate things, for instance `format()` is actually `DateTime::format` PHP native method and this one has only English output no matter your settings.